# How to stop a setInterval call

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I have two HTML buttons. First button starts the JavaScript function below:

```
function generations(){
    var refresh = setInterval(function(){ mutation() }, 1000);
}
```

Works great. I want the second button to end the setInterval. I tried like this:

```
function stop(){
    clearInterval(refresh);
}
```

Doesn't work. It works if I define the "refresh" variable outside of the function, but then I can't start it when I want to, it just starts automatically. The two functions are defined in a separate .js file.

Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare it outside and separate the assignment. Set the interval inside:

```
var refresh;
function generations(){
    refresh = setInterval(function(){ mutation() }, 1000);
}
```

And stop:

```
function stop(){
    if (refresh) { 
       clearInterval(refresh); 
    }
}
```

Comment: you're a genius :) Thank you.
I've built a simple genetic algorithm that draws an image:
crashoverride.site88.net/rich.html

Answer (score 1):

`refresh` is confined into the scope of `generations()`

You have to make `refresh` global or let it be passed to `stop()` as parameter

Answer (score 1):

In your code the "refresh" variable is local only to the function it is located. If you to keep it in this manner you should do something like this:

```
var refresh;

function generations(){
    refresh = setInterval(function(){ mutation() }, 1000);
}

function stop(){
    clearInterval(refresh);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Scopes in Javascript

There are two different *scopes* available in Javascript, the first of which is called *local scope* and the second of which is called *global scope*. A scope defines how much access other functions have to a variable. Here's how it works (in essence):

- The `var` keyword declares a variable at the current scope. Inside a function this is the local scope, outside a function this is the global scope.
- From that point, that variable can only be accessed from within that scope.
- **Local Scope** is only within **one** function. A variable in local scope can only be accessed from within that function, and is deleted once it finishes running.
- **Global Scope** is within **all** functions. It is accessible by all functions, and is only deleted when the browser tab / window is closed (or the Javascript process is killed).

Note that commonly we like to call variables in the local scope *local variables* and variables in the global scope *global variables*.

### In your code

The variable that you declare, `refresh`, is a local variable because you declare it inline in the `generations` function. Thus, it is only accessible in the scope of that function, and not to any others. This means that it is not able to be used by the `stop` function.

If you if you want `refresh` to be accessiable by `stop`, you need global scope - i.e. refresh needs to be declared outside of a function. This means that it is accessible for read / write by all other functions in the code.

An example of how your new code would look (this solves your problem):

```
var refresh; //Declare refresh in the global scope, but don't assign it a value
function generations(){
    refresh = setInterval(function(){ mutation() }, 1000); //Assign a value
}
function stop(){
    clearInterval(refresh); //Read that value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is you have to clear your interval before reinitializing it.

Keep the refresh variable in outside scope so you can reference it as well.

```
var refresh;
function generations(){
    if( refresh ){ 
      stop()
    }
    refresh = setInterval(function(){ mutation() }, 1000);
}

function stop(){
    clearInterval(refresh);
}
```